# Skipping InitAndApply and Destroy

Tags: terratest

Is there a way to skip the `InitAndApply` and `Destroy` phases of the test?

I want to just `terraform output` and build out my test assertions with `testify/assert`

Answer (score 0):

It does not fit very well for `Terratest` to skip the `init` and `apply` phases. Just because `Terratest` is an end-to-end test tool. According to the Terraform blog post [Testing HashiCorp Terraform](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/testing-hashicorp-terraform), `Terratest` as and end-to-end tool aims to answer the question:

> Can someone use the infrastructure system successfully?” For example, application developers should still be able to deploy to HashiCorp Nomad after you upgrade the version.

For the type of test that you are looking for you might use a simple unit test like `terraform validate` that do not require active infrastructure resources or authentication to an infrastructure provider. Other tools for Terraform unit test can be found at the [Some examples of Test-Driven Development for Infrastructure](https://github.com/joatmon08/tdd-infrastructure) git repo.